# Jquery video slider with autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to ask, if do you know any jquery based solution, to create slider with html5 video as content ?

This slider should auto change slides, and autoplay them. But when next slide shows and play, previous sholud stop.

I have found some nice:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/video.php

But i see, that this slider supports Youtube videos, and i need videos hosted on my server.

Comment: Something like this http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/BigVideoSlideshow/?

Comment: Hey, i'll check as this looks good - i see only, that on my firefox, performance is poor, but i'll check, thanks.

Comment: I think the `performance is poor` because of the resolution of the movies (it's full screen) on the page. But it was an idea..